# Why can't I get another users OAuth data into my Google Sheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth, google-api, google-plus-signin

All I want to do (for now) is have the end user authorize, via Oauth, permission to view email address, and have the script put that email address into my spreadsheet.

In testing, this works great. Buttons are clicked, tokens are exchanged, magic is made, all as expected when using my account, but when I publish and test with another account I get:

> The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again.

When I change...

> "Execute the app as: Me"

to...

> "Execute the app as: User accessing the web app"

...the second test account works, but I get no results on my end (obviously).
This makes me think that I've hit some limitation with the data exchanging across accounts, but this just doesn't seem right. This seems like a pretty normal thing to attempt. Maybe I'm wrong.

I'm happy to edit this question and share any code needed, but I'm pretty much using code straight off of [googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/9ac84c02bec91f77ce19a00179bee34b9faceda9/samples/GooglePlus.gs)

I guess I'm mostly asking if I can do what I'm trying to.

[Here's the web-app.](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzv93m75cHEOj-3l_oNz5tJEY3Lnz2rQzStg_oaxQH7fQa78vg/exec)

Please help

Comment: Does the other account have access to the spreadsheet? Since this is a web app, you will need to be using openById() or OpenByUrl() to specify the spreadsheet and the user that runs the script on the web form, also has to have edit access to the spreadsheet as it will be the same as that user opens the spreadsheet and tries to edit. If you use "Execute as Me" then the user will be running the script as your account and obviously it will try to work with Your token, not that users.

Comment: At the moment it's not connected to a spreadsheet. It's only trying to Logger.log the email (in preparation for the spreadsheet).

Comment: I don't want them to have access to the spreadsheet for security, so I'm running the app as "me". I want them to provide email, that's why I'm asking them to authorize with oauth. If I can't do this combination then why did google make an oauth for Google Apps Script? The "Advanced Google Services" in GAS asks for permissions, but not to give one account access to info from another, so why create a separate oauth if not for situations like this? I'm certain that I'm just missing some sort of obvious knowledge, so thank you for the help!

Comment: Check this [thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1/issues/3) and this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4315) if it can help you. This issues also get the same error "The state token is invalid or has expired". So maybe it can give you an idea on how to solve that.

Comment: I've read those, and many others. The problem I'm having seems different in that it does work, just not when deployed to the end user. The code seems right, something must be wrong with my implementation of it. @Vytautas seems closest in that it's using my token for the other user, but then, how do I get it to use each users token for each user? See GitHub issues https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/issues/48 and https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/issues/49.